Prove that $2^{x+y}-27$ divides $2^{x}+15$ has no solution
$2^{x+y}-27$ divides $2^{x}+15$ has no solution in $\mathbb N^2$
Note : that we are looking for solutions where $\frac{2^{x}+15}{2^{x+y}-27}>0$
I really want an arithmetic proof that doesn't involve discussing separate cases like $x=1$ or $x=2$ or $x=3$ ect...
Obviously , the first thing to notice is that the denominator must be positive !
So $2^{x+y} > 27 \Rightarrow 2^{x+y} \ge 28 \Rightarrow x+y \ge \frac{ln(28)}{ln(2)}  \approx 4.80735492206 \Rightarrow x+y \ge 5$
Then, i tried to let $N=2^{x+y}-27 \Rightarrow  2^{x+y} \equiv 27 \pmod{N}$
As $2^{x+y}-27$ divides $2^{x}+15$, $\Rightarrow 2^{x} \equiv -15 \pmod{N}$
So, by substituting $2^{x}$ in the first equation we get $-15 \times 2^y \equiv 27 \pmod{N} $
As $\gcd(N,3) =1 , \Rightarrow -5\times 2^y \equiv 9 \pmod{N} \Rightarrow  N \mid 9 + 5\times2^y \Rightarrow 2^{x+y}-27$ divides $9 + 5\times2^y$
But i get stuck here !
Thanks for help !

$2^{x+y}-27$ is typically greater than $2^x+15$.  Even if $y=1$, the only cases would be $x\in {1,2,3,4,5}$.

I really want an arithmetic proof that doesn't involve discussing separate cases

Please clarify if you're asking whether the intended quotient is $\frac{2^{x+y}-27}{2^{x}+15}$ or $\frac{2^{x}+15}{2^{x+y}-27}$.

But there are so few cases to look at, I don't see the point.   And why should the denominator be positive?  A negative integer can divide a positive one.

This fraction => $\frac{2^{x}+15}{2^{x+y}-27}$

For instance $(x,y)=(2,1)$ is a solution, though $2^{2+1}-27=-19$.  Note that the existence of one solution pretty much precludes a modular proof that no solutions exist.

It looks to me like you might be rather interested in the greatest common divisor.

As i said we are working in $\mathbf{N}$ , so no negative numbers are include !

The solution $(x,y)=(2,1)$ is a solution in natural numbers.

$(2,1)$ gaves a negative solution !

As I say, the solution $(2,1)$, even if you choose to ignore it, shows that modular approaches are very unlikely to work.

$\frac{2^{2}+15}{2^{2+1}-27} = -1 < 0 $

I know that modular approaches may look unlikely to work , but i've just presented what i've tried to do !

Do you have any ideas ?

Yes, check the handful of cases to confirm that $(2,1)$ is the only solution.  It only takes a minute.  If you want to exclude that solution because one of the terms is negative you certainly can, but you should add that condition to the problem statement.  I'll post the quick enumeration below.

To the Original Poster: You may be misinterpreting the problem.  When the problem specifies that the solution must be in $~\Bbb{N^2},~$ that specifies that $~(x,y) \in \Bbb{N^2},~$ but does not require that $$\frac{2^x + 15}{2^{x+y} - 27} > 0.$$  So, if this added constraint represents your interpretation, rather than the explicit specification of the problem composer, then $~(x,y) = (2,1)~$ is in fact a solution.

No , $(2,1)$ isn't a solution because the main condition is that $\frac{2^{x}+15}{2^{x+y}-27}>0$

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
There are almost no cases to try, as $2^{x+y}-27$ is almost always greater than $2^x+15$.  The only cases in which the first expression is less than (or equal to) the second are $$(x,y)=\{(1,1),(2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (5,1),(1,2), (2,2), (3,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,4)\}$$
Thus there are only $11$ pairs to try, most of which can be checked mentally.
Now, in the comments the OP has mentioned that they are not interested in solutions for which one or the other term is negative.  If you add that condition, there are no solutions at all, by direct evaluation. Indeed, $6$ of those $11$ pairs fail that condition. If you don't add that condition, $(2,1)$ is a solution.
As mentioned in the comments the existence of a single solution, albeit one that produces a negative ratio, essentially precludes the existence of a modular proof though of course it might be possible to find one if you impose an additional constraint, like $y>1$ or such.
I should add:  it is not generally true that the gcd of the two terms is $1$.  Counterexamples to that (even with the postivity constraint added) include $$(x,y)=\{(20,1),(38,1),(13,2), (41,2),(7,5), (13,5), \cdots\}$$

As i said , i want an arithmetic proof that doesn't involve discussing separate cases like $x=1$ or $x=2$ or $x=3$ ect...

You didn't prove that if the first expression $2^{x+y}-27$ is less than (or equal to) the second  $2^x+15$ , why you would only get these specific solutions $$(x,y)={(1,1),(2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (5,1),(1,2), (2,2), (3,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,4)}$$
How ever, me i want $2^{x+y}-27$ to divide $2^x+15$ not just to be smaller than him !

Just try each value for $y$.  $2^{x+y}$ grows really fast.  For example, with $y=5$, $2^{x+5}-27>2^x+15$ when $x=2$.

Try to clarify this in your answer , in order to validate it !

And I realize you were hoping for a general proof, but there are so few cases that I simply don't see the point.  Would you seek a modular proof for the claim that $7$ doesn't divide $12$?  Easier to simply check.  As here, it is easy to check those $11$ pairs (or $5$ pairs with the positivity constraint).  But, of course, if anyone finds a more abstract argument, they are welcome to post it.

The details are easily supplied, and I'll leave them to you.  Again, my point is that there are very, very cases to check and they all involve very small numbers.  No need for abstract machinery.
